# Move XML tag values to other tags

Tags: xml, bash

I'm trying to create a simple script using commands that can be run in bash that will allow me to take an XML file's values and rearrange them. Taking this sample file:

```
<item1>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine1>AAA</importantLine1>
    <importantLine2>BBB</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
    <importantLine3>DDD</importantLine3>
    <nest>
        <nestedLine>EEE</nestedLine>
    </nest>
</item1>
<item2>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine1>AAA</importantLine1>
    <importantLine2>BBB</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
    <importantLine3>DDD</importantLine3>
    <nest>
        <nestedLine>EEE</nestedLine>
    </nest>
</item2>
<item3>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine1>AAA</importantLine1>
    <importantLine2>BBB</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
    <importantLine3>DDD</importantLine3>
    <nest>
        <nestedLine>EEE</nestedLine>
    </nest>
</item3>
```

...

I would like to make the output look like this, moving the values from some of the tags and putting them into one:

```
<item1>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD "AAA" BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item1>
<item2>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD "AAA" BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item2>
<item3>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD "AAA" BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item3>
```

If anything, I'd like to learn how to move the values around, not just an answer to make it happen. "Teach a man to fish..."

Comment: Why do you want to use bash? Using `xsltproc`( only 25k ) and an XSLT template would surely be easier.

Comment: should have clarified. i meant commands that can be run in bash. sorry. i'll edit it quickly

Comment: I would suggest to use xmllint and xpath.

Comment: Other common XML tools are `xmlstarlet` and `xmlto`. If by Bash you mean just the shell's built-ins, or only commonly installed core tools like Awk and `sed`, you are in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [package `xsltproc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xsltproc) this can be achieved with an XSLT file. The order of the elements is not exactly right, but without any criteria this is as good as it gets. The Output can be ordered if necessary with `<xsl:sort ...>` or so.

You have to put all the `item???` elements in one root element for this solution to work.

**reorder.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'item')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="line" /> 
      <importantLine2>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'importantLine')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),' ')"/>     
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="nest/nestedLine">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),' ')"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </importantLine2>
      <xsl:copy-of select="junkLine" /> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use this with `xsltproc`:

```
xsltproc reorder.xslt your.xml
```

**Output is:**

```
<item1>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>AAA BBB DDD [EEE ]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item1>
<item2>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>AAA BBB DDD [EEE ]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item2>
<item3>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>AAA BBB DDD [EEE ]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
</item3>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

Assuming valid XML document with *"root"* (main) node:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -u "//importantLine2" \
-x 'concat(parent::*/importantLine3, " ", parent::*/importantLine1, " ", . , 
   " [", parent::*//nestedLine, "]")' \
-d '//importantLine1 | //importantLine3 | //nest' xmlfile
```

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-O` - omit XML declaration `(<?xml ...?>)`
- `-u` - update action; the full signature: `-u or --update <xpath> -v (--value) <value> -x (--expr) <xpath>`
- `-d` - delete action; the full signature : `-d or --delete <xpath>`

---

The output:

```
<root>
  <item1>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD AAA BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
  </item1>
  <item2>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD AAA BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
  </item2>
  <item3>
    <line>ASDF</line>
    <importantLine2>DDD AAA BBB [EEE]</importantLine2>
    <junkLine>CCC</junkLine>
  </item3>
</root>
```